# Moving Express Checkout buttons on woocommerce (not Stripe)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I can find instructions on how to Move Stripe Payment Request Button, but not a single one to the new Woocommerce payments request button, which is a different instance :(

Any help is appreciated!

/** Move Stripe Payment Request Button on product page **/

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity', array( WC_Stripe_Payment_Request::instance(), 'display_payment_request_button_html' ), 1 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity', array( WC_Stripe_Payment_Request::instance(), 'display_payment_request_button_separator_html' ), 2 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', array( WC_Stripe_Payment_Request::instance(), 'display_payment_request_button_html' ), 2 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', array( WC_Stripe_Payment_Request::instance(), 'display_payment_request_button_separator_html' ), 1 );
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit more? when you say new Woocommerce Payments request button is this a specific plugin? are you able to link to documentation? other code examples since that is for stripe only?

Comment: Sorry! WC has a new feature called Woo Payments - [link] (https://woocommerce.com/payments/) - it's based on Stripe, but buttons have a different instance/call back. So, despite I can move Stripe express checkout buttons (Apple pay, GPay) to after Add to Cart button with the above code, can't figure out how to do it to Woocommmerce express checkout (Apple pay, GPay) buttons.
Again, sorry if I was not clear.